# In ruby how can we merge two given hash into single hash and replace duplicate key value with greater of both the value

Tags: ruby, hash

For example:-

```rb
hash1={"a"=>"123", "b"=>"432"}

hash2={"a"=>"439","c"=>"987"}
```

output should be:-

```rb
{"a"=>"439","b"=>"432","c"=>"987"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash1 = { "a" => "123", "b" => "432" }

hash2 = { "a" => "439", "c" => "987" }
```

Code

```
h = hash1.merge(hash2) do |k, f, s|
  f.to_i > s.to_i ? f : s
end
p h
```

Output

```
{"a"=>"439", "b"=>"432", "c"=>"987"}
```

Comment: I don't believe that this can be improved but you could replace `f.to_i > s.to_i ? f : s` with `[f, s].max_by(&:to_i)`. (I don't have a preference.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that's the nice idea, thanks.